# How the expression !A + (A . !B) = !(A.B)?

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-algebra

I have an expression `!A+(A.!B)` and on an expression solver, it gives the `!A+(A.!B) = !(A.B)?`.
The solver notified that "Apply the Absorption Law" `A.B+!A = B+!A`.

I have made the truth tables for both the expressions and the answer was correct. But the problem is I can not understand how the absorption law has got implemented to my expression `!A+(A.!B)`?

Can someone please explain in details how the absorption law has got implemented to my expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that `+ = OR`, `. = AND` and `! = NOT`.

The absorption law was applied in the very first step:

```
  !A + A.!B
= !A + !B     (if the first monomial does not hold, A is "true"
               and thus does not need to be checked again)
= !(A.B)      (De Morgan's rule)
```

Comment: Can you please explain how the absorption law gets used on my expression?

Comment: Actually I have understood that but saying for someone else's reference

Comment: @MKJ I updated the answer to directly mention the absorption law.